# Is it possible to write Elasticsearch plugins using Python language

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Is it possible to write Elasticsearch plugins using Python language. Can anyone provide your inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

No. Elasticsearch plugins are strictly Java (JVM).